# Why is "flutter pub get" command suggesting to update internal dependencies?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, pubspec

Why is `flutter pug get` command showing and suggesting updating some internal dependencies which I directly do not use in my `pubspec.yaml` file?

Below is the result of `flutter pug get` command.

```
Resolving dependencies... (1.2s)
  _fe_analyzer_shared 64.0.0 (65.0.0 available)
  analyzer 6.2.0 (6.3.0 available)
  coverage 1.6.4 (1.7.2 available)
  dart_style 2.3.2 (2.3.4 available)
  ffi 2.1.0 (2.1.2 available)
  flutter_web_auth_2 2.2.1 (3.1.1 available)
  flutter_web_auth_2_platform_interface 2.1.4 (3.1.0 available)
  hotreloader 3.0.6 (4.1.0 available)
  http 1.0.0 (1.2.0 available)
  image 4.1.3 (4.1.4 available)
  js 0.6.7 (0.7.0 available)
  matcher 0.12.16 (0.12.16+1 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.5.0 (0.8.0 available)
  meta 1.10.0 (1.11.0 available)
  package_info_plus 4.2.0 (5.0.1 available)
  path 1.8.3 (1.9.0 available)
  pointycastle 3.7.3 (3.7.4 available)
  smart_auth 1.1.1 (2.0.0 available)
  test 1.24.9 (1.25.1 available)
  test_api 0.6.1 (0.7.0 available)
  test_core 0.5.9 (0.6.0 available)
  time 2.1.3 (2.1.4 available)
  uuid 3.0.7 (4.3.3 available)
  vm_service 11.10.0 (14.0.0 available)
  web 0.3.0 (0.4.2 available)
  web_socket_channel 2.4.0 (2.4.3 available)
Got dependencies!
26 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.`
```

My pubspec.yaml file contains the dependencies listed below:

```
 environment:
       sdk: '>=3.0.0 <4.0.0'
     
     dependencies:
       flutter:
         sdk: flutter
       flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.9
       fpdart: ^1.1.0
       flutter_hooks: ^0.20.4
       hooks_riverpod: ^2.4.9
       riverpod_annotation: ^2.3.3
       freezed_annotation: ^2.4.1
       intl: ^0.19.0
       json_annotation: ^4.8.1
       modddels_annotation_fpdart: ^0.2.0
       ulid: ^2.0.0
       flex_color_scheme: ^7.3.1
       google_fonts: ^6.1.0
       theme_extensions_builder_annotation: ^3.0.0
       responsive_framework: ^1.1.1
       go_router: ^13.0.1
       shared_preferences: ^2.2.2
       pinput: ^3.0.1
       firebase_core: ^2.24.2
       firebase_auth: ^4.16.0
       isar: ^4.0.0-dev.14
       isar_flutter_libs: ^4.0.0-dev.14
       path_provider: ^2.1.2
       appwrite: ^11.0.1
     
     dev_dependencies:
       flutter_test:
         sdk: flutter
       build_runner: ^2.4.8
       freezed: ^2.4.6
       json_serializable: ^6.7.1
       custom_lint: ^0.5.8
       flutter_lints: ^3.0.1
       riverpod_generator: ^2.3.9
       riverpod_lint: ^2.3.7
       flutter_gen_runner: ^5.4.0
       modddels: ^0.2.0
       theme_extensions_builder: ^3.0.1
       go_router_builder: ^2.4.1
```

I should be only concerned about dependencies I use in pubspec.yaml file only. Why it is showing some internal dependencies like above-mentioned dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Those are additional dependencies used by the packages you declare in your `pubspec.yaml` file.

For example https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash
uses `ansicolor, args, flutter, flutter_web_plugins, html, image, js, meta, path, universal_io, xml, yaml` in their package

`flutter pub get` command ensures that all these dependencies are up to date and compatible with each other which includes direct or indirectly used dependencies.

So you no need to worry about it.